# Is there a way I can share javascript code between two AngularJS Web solutions with Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have two web applications. They are SPA solutions with the front-end logic coded in Javascript / AngularJS.

Each one has been developed as a solution and I use Visual Studio to manage the solution for my editing. They are published as applicatoins to Azure. They share C# back end code so I created a common project, added the C# code to this and included this in both solution.

The application have there own javascript but also share javascript code.

Is there any way out there that I could place javascript into a common project and have it shared? The problem for me is that my web applications expect to see content in the /content directory and that is of course just in the same project.

Comment: why not put script in js file and place it somewhere on abc.com and include the script in your html with adding those urls in script tag.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I need to be able to edit the scripts from either Visual Studio solution. The abc.com is on the cloud and when I do a deploy they completely refresh the abc.com and def.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the good news is that there are a really nice way to do it.
You can create a third project called for example Shared. This project will have all the common code that you want to share.

The next question is how to share it. Well in the project where you want to place the files, for example `MyProject.FrontEnd` select the folder where the file will goes, click with the right button and select `Add Existing File`. This will open you a popup to select the file. When you select already the file, instead of click on the button `Add`, click over a the arrow beside the `Add`, and select `Add as a link`.

[image]

With this way you will note that the file will appear in the selected folder. When you drag the linked file to the html, it will create a script tag with the src source pointing to the other project, that it's alright in development state.

In my case, I configure the MSBuild, to copy automatically the linked files when I build the solution.

I hope it helps. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would turn the JS code into a NuGet package and host it on MyGet or a private feed. Then reference it in both projects. This also allows you to version it and update later on should you so choose.

Alternatively, you could write some kind of post-build event that grabs them from a common path and places them in the project's folder.

If you use any kind of continuous integration NuGet is probably your best bet, otherwise you need to make sure whatever staging environment also has access to the directory for the post-build event.

Comment: I think your suggestion of a post build even may be the most easy if I could just include the javascript in a shared folder . I only have around ten shared scripts so it's maybe not really enough for a nuget package.